# Trying to create 2D array in C but getting a heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: malloc, buffer-overflow

Morning Gang,

I'm new to C and I have a struct to create a graph :

```
    struct map { 
        int vertices;
        int edges;
        int **edgeMatrix;
        char **names;
    };
```

Then when I try and create a new Graph via a function Graph graphNew(int v), I manage to create a new empty graph, apply values to g->vertices and g->edges but when it comes to creating the adjacency matrix for the edges I get a heap-buffer-overflow where I am trying to malloc the array of edge pointers on the heap:

```
    Graph graphNew(int v) {
        assert(v > 0);
        Graph g = malloc(sizeof(Graph));
        if(g == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, no memory allocation!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        g->vertices = v;
        g->edges = 0;
        g->edgeMatrix = malloc(v * sizeof(int *));   <---- ERROR:
```

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to see how why I am not able to create the intial array of pointers with the malloc statement for edgeMatrix. I've stepped through with GDB, g has address 0x602000000010 but then when I hit the malloc statement I generate this heap-buffer-overflow error:

[Heap-buffer-overflow error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSDYo.png)

[byte allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5MKE.png)

I've tried different combinations of pointer memory allocation statements and even though they compile, I get the same result.

Can someone assist in why I can't allocate the array of int pointers to start populating an edge matrix?

Cheers P.